# How to read json files from sub folders in ADLS and ingest them into ADX through Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I have ADLS Gen2 storage with a parent folder and multiple sub folders and each folders having json files. I want to get the file names and create table in ADX with the name of json files.

I think I have to use get metadata activity here.. the folder structure looks like this.

> /UserData/Overground/UsersFolder/ProjectName/Environment1/data/json/demo-02/2021/01/28/03/

under this folder, we have multiple json files

> demo-02-2021-01-28-03-30.json
> demo-02-2021-01-28-03-30.json
> demo-02-2021-01-28-03-30.json

other folders look also like this
and under each of these folder, multiple json files are available.

> /UserData/Overground/UsersFolder/ProjectName/Environment1/data/json/demo-02/2021/01/28/02/
> /UserData/Overground/UsersFolder/ProjectName/Environment1/data/json/demo-02/2021/01/29/04/
> /UserData/Overground/UsersFolder/ProjectName/Environment1/data/json/demo-02/2021/01/29/05/
> /UserData/Overground/UsersFolder/ProjectName/Environment1/data/json/demo-02/2022/01/01/05/

Using ADF I need to get json files from ADLS storage , create tables in ADX with the name of json files and ingest data into the tables.

```
the schema of the tables is (value:string, name:string,timestamp:date)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can the path be indeed constructed from the file name (E.g. for `demo-02-2021-01-28-03-30.json` the path is `.../02/2021/01/28/03`)?

Comment: You still didn't answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nested folder structure, loop through each folder and get the required files using the process below.

1. Using Get Metadata get the child items under the main folder and pass them to ForEach activity.
2. Inside ForEach activity add execute pipeline and pass the current item to child pipeline parameters.
3. In the child pipeline, pass the parameter value to get metadata activity to get the next child items inside the subfolder and pass them to ForEach activity.
4. Repeat the process till you get the list of files and copy them to sink using copy data activity.

Refer to these SO [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72688135/get-metadata-from-blob-storage-with-folder-like-structure-using-azure-data-fac/72715569#72715569) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901249/i-would-like-to-add-the-date-and-time-string-in-addition-to-the-source-file-name/72938601#72938601) for a similar process with repro details.